# Need to exclude word from multiple lines that contain another word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find the `FAIL`, but NOT if it's on the same line containing `Advocacy`.

Several lines on a page contain `FAIL` if the status of the service is down. I am trying to find `FAIL` in the entire document, but exclude every line that contains another word.

Example:

- `Advocacy WS  Ping  <10  FAIL   URL: https://ncweb.blackbaud.com/CapWizService/MasterService.asmx`
- `Advocacy WS  URL   <10  FAIL   Advocacy URL:`
- `Advocacy Target Service  Web Service Ping  <10  FAIL https://AdvocacyService.Blackbaudhosting.com/MasterService.asmx`
- `BBDM End Point  Ping  <10  FAIL URL: 
  https://bbisec04pro.blackbaudhosting.com/14546P_f7ca13f1-5e8f-48a5-aad2-0867d2b2f72e/Download/CustomFileDownload.ashx`

So the first 3 lines all contain Advocacy and are in failing status. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use two sequenced regex/grep

Comment: In which programming language or environment is this being attempted?

Comment: Javascript, sorry.

Comment: Despite the fact that, [somehow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/248725 "the FGITW part"), this question got a good answer, "how can I do this" questions should include code. This site is not for writing your code for you; it's for solving _specific problems_, like "I wrote this code to solve this problem, but it's also matching when `Advocacy` is before `FAIL` in the line, when it shouldn't" (or something like that).

Comment: Sorry Q! I did have my own code I tried but I didn't think to paste it here. I can do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead assertion

```
/^(?!.*Advocacy.*).*(FAIL)/gm
```

This says to match the beginning of the line, and make sure that the beginning is not followed by (any number of characters followed by "Advocacy"), but do not actually match any of that.  Then once you've checked that "Advocacy" isn't anywhere on the line, look for any number of characters, followed by "FAIL".

https://regex101.com/r/vY1yO6/2 to see it in action with your test data

Comment: I cannot use the /gm commands in my application. Is there a way to manually skip 3 lines (there will always be 3 lines that start with Advocacy) and catch the FAIL at any point after that?

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just requests for code.

Comment: Sorry Q! I did have my own code I tried but I didn't think to paste it here. I can do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

> grep FAIL < somepage.html | grep -v Advocacy

Comment: Great answer for *NIX. Sorry, this is for Javascript/Windows.